# getting a blank login page :( any way I can fix this without having to do a clean install?

Tags: custom-post-types, themes, parse

here's the site: www.evolvtec.golocalexpert.com

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in /home2/inbrazil/public_html/evolvtec/wp-content/themes/Divi/epanel/custom_functions.php on line 1264

Here is the custom_functions.php line 1264:

```
function et_add_responsive_shortcodes_css(){
global $shortname;

if ( 'on' == et_get_option( $shortname . '_responsive_shortcodes', 'on' ) )
    //responsive css if needed}
```

Comment: What does the function that contains that error look like?

Comment: You should indent your code correctly, it'll make these kinds of errors much easier to spot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(See comments by others for your PHP error - though I'd recommend a good editor or IDE to help you spot syntax errors quickly and tidy the code for you as you type.)

Re: the question title, no, you usually don't have to do a clean install if there is an error with a theme and you find yourself locked out of the main site **and** `/wp-admin`.

There's a simple way to reset to the default WordPress theme (e.g. `Twenty Fifteen`).

- In (S)FTP etc., rename the theme directory from `Divi` to `Divi-temp`
- You should now be able to access `/wp-admin` again
- You'll see this message: "The active theme is broken. Reverting to the default theme."
- Now fix your theme / restore a working copy from a backup and re-enable it.